# File name problem(?)

Tags: filenames, mv

I have downloaded audio with *youtube-dl*, and then I wanted to change name with *mv*:

```
mv "Powerwolf  - Resurrection By Erection-Hiu1hPdJk-Y.mp3" "Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3
>"
```

But, when I want to do something with renamed file, bash prints:

```
root@bananapi:~/Music# mv "Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3 " All
mv: cannot stat 'Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3 ': No such file or directory
```

When I type *ls -l*, bash prints:

```
root@bananapi:/home/music/Music# root@bananapi:/home/music/Music# ls -l
total 3860
drwxr-xr-x 2 music music    4096 Apr 19 11:49 All
-rw-r--r-- 1 music music     360 Apr 19 12:34 download.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 music music    4096 Apr 19 11:48 Eleven
drwxr-xr-x 2 music music    4096 Apr 18 20:49 KlemenSlakonja
drwxr-xr-x 2 music music    4096 Apr 19 11:49 LittleBig
drwxr-xr-x 2 music music    4096 Apr 18 20:28 Powerwolf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  3924591 Oct 24 15:03 Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3 ?
```

Now, I want to delete this file, but I can't.

Comment: Is there `?` at the end of the filename?

Comment: I think so, because bash prints it in "ls -l"

Comment: besides, why did you change the spelling of "erection" to err e double r in the target file? that looks painful.

Comment: Ooops, that's my mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial `mv` renamed the file to a name containing a newline at the end.  You forgot to close the quoted string of the new name and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  After pressing  <kbd>Enter</kbd> (inserting a newline), you closed the double quote.  This inserted a newline into the filename.

To rename the file, use

```
mv $'Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3 \n' 'Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3'
```

Note the space before the `\n`.  It looks like this should be there according to the `ls` output.

You could also use a `*` to match the end of the name with a newline:

```
mv "Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3"* "Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3"
```

Comment: That works, thaks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a newline character at the end of your new file name. It appears you have pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> before you typed the closing quote `"` at the end of your `mv` command. In order to correct that, type

```
mv "Powerwolf - Resurrection by Errection.mp3   <---  Press Enter here
" "Powerwolf - Resurrection by Erection.mp3"
```